# How to extract Cartesian gradient with more digits than 8 using Gaussian?

Tags: software, gaussian

I would like to obtain the Cartesian gradient from a Gaussian formatted checkpoint file with more digits than 8 (specified in scientific notation). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I doubt if this is necessary, since the numerical error of a gradient is typically on the order of 10^(-5), or at best 10^(-6)

Comment: +1 but I agree with wzkchem5, and additionally, the answer to your question would be to change the source code and recompile, so perhaps don't worry about it!

Comment: @wzchem5 Why do you think I do not need for it? I would like to obtain numerical second derivatives with respect to a few pairs of internal coordinates, based on the analytical gradient vector, without calculating the full Hessian. It is also OK for me if you suggest a Gaussian option which does this job. I am not aware of such an option.

Comment: I'm afraid that if you only have the formatted checkpoint file, you won't get more out of it than what you see. You will have to get it from the routines itself.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I also have the raw .chk file. Perhaps if I had the source of the formchk program, then I would be able to modify it to print more digits.

Comment: I think your comment and wzkchem5's hint that this might be an XY problem. It seems like your fundamental question is the one you mentioned in your comment (e.g. calculating select second derivatives, rather than the full Hessian). The question you asked is about retrieving gradient values at a higher precision from Gaussian. wzkchem is arguing that the numerical error in the gradient is several orders of magnitude larger than the precision you are seeking, so these new digits may just be noise. Without going through the Gaussian source code, I don't believe you can modify the chk precision.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to focus on the issue you describe in your comment. I think this is the real root of your question and seems more likely to be solvable by users here.

Comment: I agree with Tyberius. If you have the checkpoint file, you can usually use that as a starting point for further calculations. You can't extract something that simply isn't there. I think there is an iop to adjust the convergence criteria, there might be a switch to control what is printed. But I don't see myself as an expert for that anymore. So the best way to go about is to modify the question.

Comment: I recommend asking the Gaussian support, help@gaussian.com. This is probably the most straightforward way to get a definite answer. This is exactly the kind of technical question that they can answer with certainty.